# Figuring out some sum

Tags: java, sum

> You are given the sum 1 + (1+3)/2 + (1+3+5)/4 + … + (2.n-1)/ 2^(n-1).  You should compile a program that (given integer N) finds and displays the value of the sum to the N-th addend.

I've written some code but I can't figure out the formula... Help?

Here is my code:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

 System.out.print("n = ");
 int n = input.nextInt();
 double sum = 0;

 for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
     sum = sum + (2 * i - 1) / (Math.pow(2, i - 1));
 }

 System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: `2*n - 1` does not make sense to me... It does not match with the term before that, does it?

Comment: `1+3=4` `1+3+5=9` `1+3+5+7=16` `1+3+5+7+9=25`... `4` `9` `16` `25`... do you see the pattern?

Comment: Pshemo shows good technique here.  Working a problem fully by hand can often reveal patterns that aren't obvious from the basic description or from formulas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Pshemo's notice that 1+3+5+...+n = (n-1)^2 then  your formula will be

[image]

And your code will be

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("n = ");
int n = input.nextInt();
double sum = 0;

for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    sum += 2 * Math.pow(i, 2) / Math.pow(2, i);
}

System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: Ah yes :) in formula it should be i instead of n. you are right! Thanks!